# Ubuntu 14.04 Server - Can't find where my hard disk space has gone

Tags: ubuntu, storage, diskspace

I have a backuppc server running on Ubuntu 14.04. Total HD space is 293G. BackupPC states that the pool is 141.24GB. I have run this command on the backuppc dir to check space

```
du -sh /var/lib/backuppc/
```

This command verifies that the pool is the same size.

There is nothing else running on this machine, but it states that I am using 230G os space.

I have been trying to find useful scripts to try and locate the space, but none have seemed to do the job.

Can anyone advise on a command or maybe WEB UI software that would help me track this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try

> lsof |head -1
>
> lsof | grep -i deleted

You may have deleted files that an application are holding open so are still using space till that application releases them.

if you find any big ones restart the application and the space will become free

example

php-fpm is holding open files I can not see in /tmp

> COMMAND      PID    TID       USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
>
> php-fpm5. 114237              root    3u      REG              252,0         0     782061 /tmp/ZendSem.WCDzTS (deleted)
>
> php-fpm5. 114239          www-data    3u      REG              252,0         0     782061 /tmp/ZendSem.WCDzTS (deleted)
>
> php-fpm5. 114240          www-data    3u      REG              252,0         0     782061 /tmp/ZendSem.WCDzTS (deleted)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experience with [`ncdu`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncdu). It's the terminal equivalent of `baobab` or `mate-disk-usage-analyzer`:

```
sudo ncdu -x /var/lib/backuppc/
```

`-x` is for :

> Only count files and directories on the same filesystem as the
>   specified dir.

So it doesn't follow symlinks or mounted directories, and should be more accurate than `du -sh`.

If you want to check every folder except the one you mentioned :

```
sudo ncdu -x / --exclude /var/lib/backuppc/
```

You can install the [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ncdu) with `sudo apt-get install ncdu`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It's not `/var/lib/backuppc` that I want to check it is the rest of the file system.  As I know that there is 141G in the backuppc dir.  And I am trying to locate where the other 90G is.  

Can i use ncdu to exclude that dir?

Comment: Updated the answer